# Please explain how come the output is 9?

Tags: java, printing, byte, xor

The output is 9 and I can't get my head around the whole bitwise XOR concept.

```
public class XOR {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        int a = 12;
        int b = 5;
        int c = a ^ b;
        System.out.print( c );
    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should be looking at the bits.

Comment: Please know about XOR operation and how does it apply on bits.

Comment: @Rahul, he's not asking what `^` is, he's asking how XOR works.

Comment: @Mark it shouldn't be an answer because it doesn't explain how XOR works, which is the question being asked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

XOR stands for exclusive or

> Exclusive or or exclusive disjunction is a logical operation that outputs true only when inputs differ (one is true, the other is false)

in your case, it's a bitwise comparison, so each 0 and 1 at the same position is compared

[image: bitwise XOR]

first step is to translate values from decimal to binary

```
12  = 00001100
05  = 00000101
```

Then, you apply XOR

```
12  = 00001100
05  = 00000101
XOR = 00001001
```

Finally, you convert from binary to decimal

```
00001001 = 9
```

Comment: Maybe add, that it is a bitwise comparison, so each 0 and 1 at the same position is compared. Also consider adding a logic table showing a single xor operation.

Comment: Thanks man. finally some lights in this XOR concept. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

the XOR operator first converts both of your values into their binary equivalents. Binary operations will apply to corresponding bits, and the XOR operator evaluates to true (1) whenever the corresponding bits are not equal. For example, 2^1 = 3 [10 ^ 01] notice the first bits and the second bits are different, so both bits evaluate to 1.

In your example: 12 ^ 5

12 = 1 1 0 0

5  =  0 1 0 1

The first and the 4th bits are of opposite value, so the first and the fourth bits evaluate to 1, while the remaining bits evaluate to 0, so the solution is 1001 = 9